# TFS update pull request does not update the comment line

Tags: tfs, pull-request

everybody. I've the following issue, when someone makes a new pull request and I leave certain comments, if this someone, does update the pull request, TFS instead of moving my comments with the code changes, it is left on the line number, rather than the code snippet.
If someone knows how this to be fixed, as it cause enormous efforts to track if the issue was solved.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Post a screenshot for your query.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue.

This is a new feature that is only available in TFS 15 RC1 and VSTS. Older servers do not have this feature. This feature is called comment tracking and it is mentioned in the release notes [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2016-jul-7-vso.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you click to add a comment as the screenshot below, you would be able to add a comment for a line of code:

[image]

Then you'll see your comment under the line:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, what will happen if you do some changes on the code and update the pull request, so the code that was on line 14 now is on line 35. Within our TFS the comment is on line 14, but the code is already on line 35, which I want to fix. It is TFS 2015. Thanks in advance

Comment: I could reproduce your scenario. But there is no way to change this. Comments are anchored to the line number and column of the commit on which comment was made.

Comment: @sidneyelagib, just tested in the latest TFS15 RC1, the issue is fixed in this version.

Comment: @sidneyelagib, I have submitted a feedback for this issue at website https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3100703, you can vote it and track it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments

Comment: This is happening on our TFS 16